# Implementing feed in Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, hashmap

I want to implement a feed-like structure in Android that downloads some data from server and shows it in some form by parsing it.

It seems that using Hashmaps may be an answer about how to store it (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) but I am not able to understand how to dynamically update it from server push/pull.

Can anyone throw some light on how to achieve the dynamic update of Hashmap/listview so that pressing a "refresh" button can update the list with new values?

Any help is appreciated... new here at SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im just gonna give you quick example of how to do such thing,

1- first create a class that can hold our data for example

```
    public class Feeds {
    String img, title, subtitle;
    long id;

    public Feeds(long id, String img, String title, String subtitle) {
        this.id = id;
        this.img = img;
        this.title = title;
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }
    public long getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public String getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(String img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getSubtitle() {
        return subtitle;
    }

    public void setSubtitle(String subtitle) {
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }

}
```

then second create a list holding your class like `List<Feeds> iconItem = new ArrayList<Feeds>();` in your `activity class`
then third when you fetch your data from your server do this

```
iconItem.add(new Feeds(json.getLong("id"), json
                                .getString("img"), json.getString("title"),
                                json.getString("subtitle")));
```

then within your `listView adapter` `constructor`   add param like `Context c, List<Feeds> feeds`
then in your getView inside of your `Adapter` do `feed = feeds.get(position);`
now you can pass all the data to your views for example `myTextView.setText(feed.get(position).getTitle());`

and to update your listView simply add the new data to your `List` and notify the `Adapter` that there are new data simply by calling this `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Wow! I think this is perfect... will give it a try and tell you how it goes. Didn't expect such a prompt reply.. SO community rocks!

PS: Cannot upvote the answer since I don't have enough reputation points.. how do I mark this as correct answer?